# How to call a method when back button in emulator pressed

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-lifecycle

I use below code for my `ActionBar` `Button`, it can back to previous `Activity` and also display the `Toast`.

```
 case android.R.id.home:
 Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 onBackPressed();
 return true;
```

If I press back in my emulator, no Toast display. So I decide to add this

```
 public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
```

After added this, when I press the back button in the emulator, it to display `Toast` but not returning to previous `Activity`. I click the `ActionBar` `Button`, same thing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run super method :

```
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It will call normal back press, and shows `Toast`

Answer (score 1):

you have to override `onBackPressed()` method and then put your Toast there

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a dialog asking the user if they wanted to exit and then call super.onBackPressed() if they did.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Really Exit?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                WelcomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

In the above example, you'll need to replace WelcomeActivity with the name of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove this code**

```
case android.R.id.home:
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
```

**And just Use this override Method**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed()
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It will called by android itself when you press back button.
you not need to call it yourslef.